# Конструкция ArrayList<ИмяКласса>

Tags: java, android

Что в java значит такого типа конструкция `ArrayList<Sensor> sensorses = new ArrayList<Sensor>();` а именно `ArrayList<Sensor>` ? Заранее спасибо :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ArrayList<Sensor> sensorses = new ArrayList<Sensor>();`  Это создание ArrayList который может хранить в себе объекты только типа *Sensor* - `<Sensor>` это [Wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) в котором мы указываем тип данных которые принимает ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

создаем лист, элементы которого имеют определенный тип - класс Sensor